# How to get a cryptographically strong integer from 0-X in PHP?

Tags: php, random

I want to generate random alphanumeric strings in PHP. They will be used in places where the strength of random numbers is important (publicly visible IDs in URLs and the like).

As I understand, in PHP the main source of cryptographically strong randomness is `openssl_random_pseudo_bytes()`. This however returns an array of bytes, not alphanumeric characters.

To convert them to alphanumerics I could either hash them (which would produce a longer-than-necessary string of a limited set of hex characters), or `base64_encode()` them (which would produce a string with `+`, `/` and `=` in it - not alphanumerics).

So I think that instead I could use the random bytes as a source of entropy and generated my own string consisting only of the characters `0-9a-zA-Z`.

The problem then becomes - how to translate from  256 distinct values (one byte of input) to 62 distinct value (one character of output). And in a way, that all 62 characters are equally as likely. (Otherwise there will be 8 characters that appear more often than the rest).

Or perhaps I should use another approach entirely? I would like my string to be as short as possible (say, 20 characters or so - shorter URLs are better) and consist only of alphanumeric characters (so that it doesn't need to be specially escaped anywhere).

Answer (score 2):

You can implement your own base64 encoding, sort of. If you can allow two specific symbols - these can be anything, for example `.` and `-`, it doesn't really matter. It can even be a space for one of them. In any case, what you would do is this:

```
$alphabet = "0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ.-";
// using . and - for the two symbols here
$input = [123,193,21,13]; // whatever your input it, I'm assuming an array of bytes
$output = "";
foreach($input as $byte) {
    $output .= $alphabet[$byte%64];
}
```

Assuming random input, all characters have equal probability of appearing.

That being said, if you can't allow anything except pure alphanumeric, cut the symbols from the `$alphabet` and use `%62` instead of `%64`. While this does mean you have a small bias towards the chracters `0` through `7`, I don't think it's significant enough to worry about.

Answer (score 0):

I found this function on php.net in the user comments.

```
     function crypto_rand($min,$max) {
         $range = $max - $min;
         if ($range == 0) return $min; // not so random...
         $length = (int) (log($range,2) / 8) + 1;
         return $min + (hexdec(bin2hex(openssl_random_pseudo_bytes($length,$s))) % $range);
     }
```

Then do something like

```
 for($i=0; $i<20; $i++)
  {
    $string.= chr(crypto_rand(1,26)+96); //or +64 for upper case
  }
```

Or similar.

Answer (score 0):

*note: THIS IS WRONG! I leave this attempted answer for reference only.*

(31 * 256) % 62 = 0

For each output alphanumeric character, generate 31 random values. Sum these 31 values and take the modulo 62.

Kind of brutal, but this is the only "mathematicaly correct" option I can think of :)

Comment: What if I discard bytes in the 248-255 range if I come across them? Would that be mathematically correct too?

Comment: @Vilx- well I couldn't tell for sure, but so it seems. This could be much more sensible an option :) and now I realise this is probably what the deleted answer meant...

Comment: Hmm, I think this is pretty wrong actually. Think about it - if you have two dice (standard 6-sided), and you roll them, the most common sum will be 7. That's because there are 6 ways the dice can roll to get "7", while there is only 1 way they can roll to get "2". The same here.

Comment: A better analogy would be: what are the odds of obtaining an even number with one die vs. with two dice (sum(dice)%2 = 0). The probability is the same in both cases. Not sure if it still applies with three dice. I think I'm going to ask at http://math.stackexchange.com :)

Comment: I'm interested too. :) Can you give me a link to your question? :)

Comment: Sorry it took me so long to get back to you. I manually established the list of possible outcomes with three dice, it was easy to see that the likelihood of the sum be a multiple of 3 is *not* 1/3. My suggestion is wrong. I'll leave my answer for reference only.

Comment: Btw, discarding values in the 248-255 range is probably the best option, I believe.